# Why are certain custom fields not allowed in Shield Platform Encryption?

Tags: salesforcedx, shield-encryption

Hi I was wondering why Formula, Checkbox, Number and Picklist data types are not allowed to be encrypted? If so are there any workarounds for this one?

I read a lot of documentation regarding Shield Platform Encryption and I can't find any statement in regards to why some of this custom fields are not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Formula** - these aren't saved in the database so no need need to encrypt-at-rest (which is what Shield Platform Encryption is)

**Checkbox and Picklist** - I had a discussion with the PM about this about a year ago and the answer was basically "we won't do this without also being able to resolve side effects - such as supporting searches, list view filters, report filters, picklist data changes, etc.

As for workaounds - you need to shadow copy (in Apex) these field values into custom text (encrypted) fields - then in Apex clear the values.

Checkbox -> Text with value "TRUE" or "FALSE" (or "T" or "F" - it is really your decision)

Picklist  -> Text (straight copy)

You'll lose some OOTB benefits of these fields, especially in report/list view filters as users won't be prompted with the allowed value sets

Comment: Thanks a lot! Kinda new to this shield platform encryption, and they want us to implement it, I just want to have an answer if ever they ask me why these fields are not supported. and Last, how about numbers? Do you have any idea why we can't encrypt them? @cropredy

Comment: I'd be speculating but, for example, there's no Order By Soql support which is kind of important for numbers.   Basically, the primary use case for Shield platform encryption appears to encryption at rest of PII data (although Contact.Birthdate is not supported)

Comment: last question, How come contact.dateOfBirth is not allowed to be encrypted but custom date is allowed to probabilistic? @cropredy

Comment: No idea.  Because of that, is why I came up with shadow fields in our org to handle that (and a picklist for gender)

Comment: There is an open Idea to add this functionality to the Platform Encryption:
https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000lKgsQAE